# Submitting a form with ajax within infowindow GoogleMaps API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps, infowindow

Development newbie here. I'm trying to have a form inside each of my infowindows on a google map on my website. I have one function that generates all of the markers as well as the content of each of the markers.

My problem is that the jQuery that should be called after a form in my infowindow is submitted never called (at least addComment.php is never called). I've looked around a lot and couldn't find anything to fix this problem. Any help would be very appreciated

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64806723893503, -90.30880584275044),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var pdata;
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'fetchInfo.php', data: pdata, dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    var content = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {  

        content[i] = '<div> '+ response[i].added;

        content[i] += '<div class=description>'+response[i].desc+'</div>';
        content[i] += '</div>';
        content[i] += '<div class=addCom>';
        content[i] += '<textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="comment" id="comment" data-picId='+response[i].picture_id+' placeholder="Enter Comment Here..."></textarea><br>';
        content[i] += '<input class="submitComment" type="button" value="Add Comment"/>';
        content[i] += '</div>';

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lng),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                map.panTo(marker.position);
                infowindow.setContent(content[i]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}});
```

Then, separate from this function I have a jQuery that performs the ajax call

```
 $(".submitComment").click( function(){
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-picId');
    var user_id = usrId;
    if (comment === ""){
        return;
    }
    var pdata = {
        comment : comment,
        picture_id : picture_id,
        user_id : user_id
    };
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'addComment.php', data: pdata, dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
        if(response.success){ 
            $("#uploadfile_input").val("");
            $("#lat").val("");
            $("#lng").val("");
            $("#desc").val("");
            load();
        }
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your script , there are some points of facts.

- First of all attribute 'id' is meant to be uniqueness so you must assign unique ids to comments. `content[i] += '<textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="comment" id="comment" data-picId='+response[i].picture_id+' placeholder="Enter Comment Here..."></textarea><br>';`
- An event listener must be applied after the element is available in DOM. In this case when a new form is added an event listener should be applied on it after infoWindow is created, then use $.submit() event to subscribe this form submission and use serializeForm() to meet dynamic concerns.

```js
for(){
            content[i] = '<form><div> '+ response[i].added;
    
            content[i] += '<div class=description>'+response[i].desc+'</div>';
            content[i] += '</div>';
            content[i] += '<div class=addCom>';
            content[i] += '<textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="comment" id="comment" data-picId='+response[i].picture_id+' placeholder="Enter Comment Here..."></textarea><br>';
            content[i] += '<input class="submitComment" type="button" value="Add Comment"/>';
            content[i] += '</div></form>';
   

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        map.panTo(marker.position);
                        infowindow.setContent(content[i]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i)); 
        $(content[i]).submit(listenformSubmission());
        }
            function listenformSubmission(){
                var comment = $(this).find('[name="comment"]');//here will be the form object
                var picture_id = comment.attr('data-picId');
                var user_id = usrId;
                if (comment === ""){
                    return;
                }
                var pdata = {
                    comment : comment,
                    picture_id : picture_id,
                    user_id : user_id
                };
                $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'addComment.php', data: pdata, dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
                    if(response.success){ 
                        $("#uploadfile_input").val("");
                        $("#lat").val("");
                        $("#lng").val("");
                        $("#desc").val("");
                        load();
                    }
                }
        return false;
                }
```

Here is the more detail with sample code
I am not removing the above answer as explanation to this answer.
Here is a code which might assist you in this case.
First of all I wrote a click listener to be available in the memory

```
 function addCommentForm(el){
 var formdata = $(el);
   var siblings = formdata.siblings();
    var comments= $(siblings[1]).val();
       console.log(comments);
        if (comments === "") {
            return;
        }
        var pdata = {
            comment:comments

        };
    console.log(pdata);
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST', url: 'addComment.php', data: pdata, dataType: 'json', success: function (response) {

               alert((JSON.stringify(response)));
                }

        });
    return false;

}
```

and here is the init Function where the story starts

```
 function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64806723893503, -90.30880584275044),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    //  alert("ok");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pdata;
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'fetchInfo.php',
                    data: {},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        var marker, i;
                        console.log(response);
                        var content = [];
                        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            content[i] = '<form ><div> ' + response[i].added;

                            content[i] += '</div>';
                            content[i] += '<div class=addCom>';
                            content[i] += '<div class=description>' + response[i].desc + '</div>';
                            content[i] += '<textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="comment" id="comment" data-picId=' + response[i].picture_id + ' placeholder="Enter Comment Here..."></textarea><br>';
                            content[i] += '<input onclick="return addCommentForm(this);" class="submitComment" type="button" value="Add Comment"/>';
                            content[i] += '</div></form>';
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lng),
                                map: map
                            })
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                                return function () {
                                    console.log($(content[i]));
                                    map.panTo(marker.position);
                                                                       infowindow.setContent(content[i]);


                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                }
                            })(marker, i));

                        }
                    }
                });
    });
}
```

I wrote some PHP SCRIPTS  to check the response and here it is
**fetchInfo.php**

```
    <?php
echo json_encode(array(array(
    'lat'=>"38.64806723893503",
    'lng'=>"-90.30880584275044",
    'added'=>"1",
    'desc'=>"Descripion of map",
    'picture_id'=>1
)));
```

and **addComment.php** to check the response is recieved

```
    <?php
      echo json_encode(
    array('result'=>true,
    'submitdata'=>$_POST
    )
    );
```

I am adding a link of running script I have put on a server.
[EXAMPLE](http://tutorials.technacron.com/maptrick/)